# How to remove the Gatein portal container resources from head tag

Tags: javascript, resources, portal, gatein

We created a Gatein Portal Site and when we accessed that using the below url.

localhost:8080/portal/myportal, there are few resources loaded from the gatein portal container to head tag.

Please refer the below source of the portal site script included by the Gatein Portal container. Please let me know how to remove these portal container resources from the head tag.

Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var require = {
    "shim" : {
        "PORTLET/web/SiteMapPortlet" : {
            "deps" : [ "SHARED/bootstrap" ]
        },
        "PORTLET/dashboard/TabbedDashboardPortlet" : {
            "deps" : [ "SHARED/bootstrap" ]
        },
        "PORTLET/web/IFramePortlet" : {
            "deps" : [ "SHARED/bootstrap" ]
        }
    },
    "paths" : {
        "SHARED/uiMaskLayer" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/baseGRP-en-min",
        "SHARED/uiCalendar" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/webuiExtGRP-min",
        "SHARED/navigation" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/navigation-min",
        "SHARED/org_gatein_responsive_menu" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/org_gatein_responsive_menu-min",
        "SHARED/dropdownmenu_jquery" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/dropdownmenu_jquery-min",
        "PORTLET/dashboard/TabbedDashboardPortlet" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/PORTLET/dashboard:TabbedDashboardPortlet-min",
        "SHARED/org_gatein_jppinformation" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/org_gatein_jppinformation-min",
        "SHARED/gadget" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/gadget-en-min",
        "SHARED/org_gatein_features" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/org_gatein_features-min",
        "SHARED/common" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/common-min",
        "SHARED/portalDragDrop" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/portalGRP-min",
        "SHARED/webui-ext" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/webuiExtGRP-min",
        "PORTLET/web/SiteMapPortlet" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/PORTLET/web:SiteMapPortlet-min",
        "SHARED/org_gatein_navigation" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/org_gatein_navigation-min",
        "SHARED/base" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/baseGRP-en-min",
        "SHARED/bootstrap" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/bootstrap-min",
        "SHARED/portal" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/portalGRP-min",
        "SHARED/I18NMessage" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/baseGRP-en-min",
        "SHARED/org_gatein_responsive_collapsiblecontainer" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/org_gatein_responsive_collapsiblecontainer-min",
        "SHARED/toggleContainer" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/toggleContainer-min",
        "SHARED/jpp_info_modernizr" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/jpp_info_modernizr-min",
        "SHARED/portalRequest" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/baseGRP-en-min",
        "SHARED/upload" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/webuiExtGRP-min",
        "SHARED/portalControl" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/webuiGRP-min",
        "SHARED/dashboard" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/dashboard-min",
        "SHARED/modernizr" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/modernizr-min",
        "SHARED/uiVirtualList" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/webuiExtGRP-min",
        "PORTLET/web/IFramePortlet" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/PORTLET/web:IFramePortlet-min",
        "SHARED/portalComposer" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/portalGRP-min",
        "SHARED/popupCategory" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/baseGRP-en-min",
        "SHARED/org_gatein_responsive_dropdownmenu_jquery" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/org_gatein_responsive_dropdownmenu_jquery-min",
        "SHARED/uiMaskWorkspace" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/baseGRP-en-min",
        "SHARED/uiPopup" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/baseGRP-en-min",
        "SHARED/uiForm" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/webuiGRP-min",
        "SHARED/skin" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/baseGRP-en-min",
        "SHARED/uiPopupWindow" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/webuiGRP-min",
        "SHARED/jquery" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/jquery-min",
        "SHARED/selectors" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/webuiGRP-min",
        "SHARED/uiRightClickPopupMenu" : "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/webuiExtGRP-min"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This javascript snippet defines all the declared js modules (AMD modules) in the platform. That does not mean that the resources are loaded. They are only declared.
When a script needs one of these resources, it is dynamically loaded. For example, as defined in this config, if the portlet SiteMapPortlet is displayed on the page, the script PORTLET/web/SiteMapPortlet (/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/PORTLET/web:SiteMapPortlet-min.js) is loaded and also the dependency SHARED/bootstrap (/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/SHARED/bootstrap-min.js).
If the portlet is not displayed, these scripts are not necessarely loaded.

Therefore you must not remove this javascript snippet. All the javascript features of GateIn depend on it.

You will find detailed explanations on Javascript capabilities of GateIn in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/GTNPORTAL36/JavaScript+in+GateIn

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. We are planning to host the application behind TAM WebSeal as per our enterprise standards and when we do that; TAM adds a additional junction name to the url. www.domain.com/junction/portal/myportal. Due to this, the url's available in head tag are not resolved properly and it created new jsession id's. Do you know if there is way to customize the js resources url through some configuration ? e.g "/portal/scripts/3.6.3.Final-redhat-4/GROUP/baseGRP-en-min.js"

Comment: If you need to add the /junction prefix to the js path, I guess the better way is to override the JavascriptConfigService component. The JSON set in the "require" var is returned by the getJSConfig method of this service. So you can create your own JavascriptConfigService component (for example MyJavascriptConfigService), which extends org.exoplatform.web.application.javascript.JavascriptConfigService and override the method getJSConfig in order to add your path prefix. Then declare your component in the gatein configuration. But I have never user WebSeal, so I don't know if it works.